# Get the dropdownlist data in controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list in my view I want to get the value user selects in my controller action method.

View

```
Specialty Name Active:

 <td>
    <select name="Specialty" id="Specialty"> 
            <option>--Select--</option>  
            <option value="1">True</option>
            <option value="0">False</option>
     </select>
 </td>
```

Model:

```
  public class GazelleInfoModel
{
    public GazelleInfo gazelleInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<WCG.Data.EntityObjects.GazelleInfo> ReportModel { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateNewGazelleInfo(GazelleInfoModel gazelleinfoModel, string hdnId, )
            {
                if (!isActive)
                    return LogOut();
                ViewData["CurrentPage"] = "Create New GazelleInfo";
                GazelleInfo gaz = null;
                if (gaz == null)
                {
                    gaz = new GazelleInfo();
                }
                gaz.SpecialtyName = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.SpecialtyName;
                gaz.SpecialtyNameActive=
                gaz.PreferredLanguage = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.PreferredLanguage;
                gaz.PreferredLanguageActive =       gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.PreferredLanguageActive;
                gaz.Race = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.Race;
                gaz.RaceActive = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.RaceActive;
                gaz.Ethnicity = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.Ethnicity;
                gaz.EthnicityActive = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.EthnicityActive;
                gaz.HolidayName = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.HolidayName;
                gaz.HolidayNameActive = gazelleinfoModel.gazelleInfo.HolidayNameActive;


                GazelleInfoBo.SaveOrUpdate(gaz);
```

What I need is storing the values selected in the drop downlist in the gaz object which at a later point of time i will store in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
var Specialty = Request.Form["Specialty"];// here request.form is used to get Specialty form variable.
```

**Option 2 :** I would suggest you to use MVC ModelBinding and Html Helpers.

**Model** - Add new property Specialty

**Controller** - get all relevant Specialities

```
 ViewBag.Specialities= new SelectList(Specialities, "Value", "Text");
```

**View** - User strongly type html helper

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Specialty , new SelectList(ViewBag.Specialities, "Value", "Text", Model.Specialty ))
```

**Option 3** - Best practice to have radiobuttons(where possible) to implement true/false logic.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>x.Specialty, true)True
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>x.Specialty, false)False
```

Comment: can u tell me how to get the value of the radio in a Boolean variable in controller

Comment: @RiturajMishra In the same way. You must read MVC Model Binding,strongly type view and FormCollection.